# How to descend within the “Tree of primitive Pythagorean triples”?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

It is [well-known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples) that the set of all primitive Pythagorean triples has the structure of an infinite ternary rooted tree.

What is the exact algorithm (*i.e.*, formula, or possibly set of three formulas) by which one can take a given Pythagorean triple $(a,b,c)$ and find the immediately smaller triple in the tree? For example, given $(165,52,173)$, how does one obtain its [unique] “ancestor” triple $(77,36,85)$?

Comment: I've done a writeup on a geometric mechanism of traversing this tree [here](http://everything2.com/user/abiessu/writeups/Pythagorean+Triple).  The exact formula is $(abs(p-2q),q)\text{ or }(q,abs(p-2q))$, assuming you are able to resolve $(a,b,c)$ to the $p,q$ generating pair.

Comment: This formula is derived directly from the reverse-direction three-way formula $(p+2q,q), (2p+q,p), (2p-q,p)$.  In all these formulas, we have $(a,b,c)=(p^2-q^2,2pq,p^2+q^2)$.

Comment: Better pay attention to the search for solutions Diofantos equation of the form: $aX^2+bXY+cY^2=jZ^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with $(165,52,173)$, we attempt to find the $p,q$ pair which generates this triple, i.e., $p^2-q^2=165,2pq=52,p^2+q^2=173$.  Clearly, we have $2q^2=173-165=8\implies q=2$ and thus $p=13$.

The ancestor of this triple arises from $(|p-2q|,q)\text{ or }(q,|p-2q|)$, whichever places $p',q'$ in largest-to-smallest order.  In this case, we have $p-2q=9$ and thus the ancestor pair is $(p',q')=(9,2)$ and therefore the ancestor triple is $(p'^2-q'^2,2p'q',p'^2+q'^2)=(77,36,85)$.

Comment: Is it not possible to avoid the sign issue? i.e., Is there no formula which can take any Pythagorean triple of __positive__ integers $(a_n,b_n,c_n)$ and give its “ancestor” triple $(a_{n-1},b_{n-1},c_{n-1})$ __with all three elements positive__?

Answer (score 3):

Two Trees of Pythagorean triples are known to exist (Berggren's and Price's), so to answer your question you need to first identify which one you are talking about. Descent/Ascent algorithms for both trees are given the following paper.

Bernhart, F.R. & Price, H.L. Pythagoras’ garden, revisited. Aust. Sr. Math. J. 26, 29–40 (2012). http://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ992372.pdf.

Comment: It seems there are at least three trees of Pythagorean triples (cf. McCullough). I'm hoping one of them — or some other one I don't know about — allows a descent without sign changes.

Comment: F.J.M. Barning (1963) rediscovered the same tree Berggren had found in 1934.  McCullough didn't know about Berggren, and he refers to that tree as the "Barning tree" so I don't think a third tree can be attributed to McCullough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the matrix transformations found here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples#Pythagorean_triples_by_use_of_matrices_and_linear_transformations

to ascend the tree of triples. To decend, just use the inverse matrices (which look similar except for some signs being flipped). You can try each inverse in turn but, in fact, you only need use any of the three inverses. If it was not the correct one (meaning not the one used to ascend to the current triple), you will get the ancestor triple anyway, only some of the lengths will be negative. So just take the absolute value and you're done.

For example
$$\left(\begin{array}[ccc]11 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 3\end{array}\right)^{-1}.\left(\begin{array}[c]1165\\ 52\\173\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}[ccc]11 & 2 & -2 \\ 2 & 1 & -2 \\ -2 & -2 & 3\end{array}\right).\left(\begin{array}[c]1165\\ 52\\173\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}[c] 0-77 \\ 36\\85\end{array}\right) $$

Comment: If we start with an [indeterminate] triple $(a,b,c)$, is there a single expression in [polynomials of?] $a,b,c$ that we can use to represent the fundamental $(3,4,5)$?

Comment: Is it not possible to avoid the sign issue? i.e., Is there no formula which can take any Pythagorean triple of __positive__ integers $(a_n,b_n,c_n)$ and give its “ancestor” triple $(a_{n-1},b_{n-1},c_{n-1})$ __with all three elements positive__?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan A formula would then be: Use the matrix multiply and then take the absolute value. This is what you're asking for unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: I want to avoid having to use the absolute value.

Comment: Then I do not understand what you mean by 'formula'. It sounds like you have a list of functions that are blacklisted.

Comment: If by "blacklisted" you mean "I don't want you to use them", then I think the complete set is "the absolute value function".

Comment: An example… Given: the primitive triple $$\bigl(14x^3,(x^3-7)y^2, x^3y^2+7y^2-14x^3\bigr),$$ where $x$ and $y$ are indeterminate positive integers _but we know for sure the three elements in the triple are all positive_. Required: the ancestor triple __with all three elements positive__.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: in your example, I see that if we say $2pq=14x^3$ then we can also say $2q^2+2pq=14y^2$, which gives us $7\mid q$.  We also get $2p^2+2pq=2x^3y^2$, which gives us $x\mid p$.  If $y$ is even, then we have $4pq=(x^3-7)y^2$ as our starting point...  I'm not sure about where to go next, I'll have to get out a pen and paper tomorrow...

Comment: @abiessu: Note that the triple given was derived from the Mordell equation $y^2=x^3+7$, which has no integer solutions — so it should follow that there are no integers $p,q$ satisfying the requirements. I'm hoping you'll be able to prove that. But I'm also still hoping for a single formula — which avoids the absolute value, and does not require multiple cases based on the relative magnitudes of the components of a given triple — by which one can descend/demote a triple to its [unique] ancestor.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: I can't say that I have much experience with such a venture, but it sounds interesting.  I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: by the given design of that example, you seem to be saying that although there are numbers supplied as $(a,b,c)$ in a triple, they may not necessarily be a Pythagorean Triple for a given $x,y$, is that right?  And following that logic, we would prove that there are no Pythagorean Triples arising from the specified formulas...

Comment: @abiessu: Precisely. I've turned the _hypothetical_ integer solutions to $y^2=x^3+7$ into a _hypothetical_ primitive Pythagorean triple, and am now trying to use properties of Pythagorean triples (and/or rational right triangles) to show that there are no such integers.

Answer (score 1):

I am coming to this question a bit late. In the orthogonal group of the quadratic form $x^2+y^2-z^2$ there is a reflection you can use to find the parent of each primitive Pythagorean triple (up to sign, as others have noted, and changing signs to make all coordinates positive is another reflection). See Examples 3.2 and 3.3, and the proof of Corollary 3.4, in https://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/descentPythag.pdf. The key reflection $s_{123}$ is defined in equation (3.3) there.

This description using a geometric language (in an orthogonal group that is not the standard orthogonal group of 3-dimensional space) does not rely directly on the parametrization formula for primitive Pythagorean triples.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary rooted tree of Pythagorean triples never made sense to me and has no order that can be sensed just by looking at it. What makes more sense is a pattern of sets within the subset of triples where $GCD(A,B,C)$ is an odd square. This subset includes all primitives. Here is a sample:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & Triple_1 & Triple_2 & Triple_3 & Triple_4 & Triple_5   &  Triple_6  \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61 & 13,84,85 \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89 & 45,108,117 \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125 & 85,132,157 \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169 & 133,156,205 \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221 & 189,180,261 \\ \hline
Set_{6} &143,24,145 &165,52,173 &187,84,205 &209,120,241 &231,160,281 & 253,204,325 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The formula that generates these triples may be used to find successor or predecessor simply by increasing or decreasing the values of $n$ or $k$.

$$A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k \qquad B=2(2n-1)k+2k^2\qquad  C=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2 $$

Comment: What an interesting formulation! Is this known/classical? If so, do you have any links or references? If not, have you proven that all primitives are included, whether there are any duplications, etc.?

Comment: @Kieren MacMillan  This formula is original to me, as far as I know. I discovered it via millions of spreadsheet formulas  when I knew nothing about finding Pythagorean triples, not even Euclid's formula. I have not been able to find references to it in dozens of books I've bought or online in web pages or [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369742/looking-for-references-to-pythagorean-triple-subsets). I've been writing a paper on it and how 'it' and. Euclid's formula may be used to find "triples on demand". Let me know if you find reference to these sets or formula elsewhere.

Comment: @@Kieren MacMillan I have proven that all primitives are generated in my paper. First I prove $A^2+B^2=C^2$. Then I prove that $GCD(A,B,C)=(2x-1)^2, x\in\mathbb{N}$. Then I assume that I am missing triples by adding $x$ to the increment of $A$-values. The conclusion is that $B$ cannot be an integer if $2(2n-1)$ does not divide $x$.

Comment: Dickson proved the solution $(r+s,r+t,r+s+t)$ where $2st=r^2$ is a square. With the substitution $(r,s,t)=(2k(2n-1),(2n-1)^2,2k^2)$, we have your solution. It may be that Dickson’s is more general (e.g., $s$ and $t$ don’t have to be squares in his solution); I’d have to do more investigation to determine that  for certain.

Comment: Page 8 in <https://www.jstor.org/stable/2968644> has Dickson’s solution. He does require $\gcd(s,t)=1$ [note: $s$ and $t$ are written as $m$ and $n$ in the original paper], so your solution is exactly the same as Dickson’s.

Comment: I believe your table is the ternary tree in disguise, the three “branches” being: RIGHT (equivalent to $c=b+1$), DOWN (equivalent to $c=a+2$), and DIAGONALLY (equivalent to $b=a+1$). That being said, it is perhaps a more intuitive presentation.