# What is the Equation for every possible solution to the Pythagorean Theorem where a and b are x and y coordinates on a graph.

Tags: pythagorean-triples

I currently am working on a minor programming project, and I have a program that can plot points in the problem above. However, this requires a lot of computing power that the average school chromebook simply cannot output. I realized that the points were very specifically placed and followed a pattern, but I have no idea where to start linking the info together.
[Solutions from the range (-30,-30) to (30,30)][1]
If anyone is interested in the code:

```
var a;
var b;
var c;
var list=[];
// Find A and B
for(var i = -30; i<=30; i++){
  a=i;
  console.log(a);
 for(var j = -30; j<=30; j++){
  b=j;
  console.log(b);
  wholenum(a, b);
  }
}


// Test If a^2+b^2 makes a whole number
function wholenum(a, b) {
  if(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(a^2+b^2)) === Math.sqrt(a^2+b^2)){
    c=Math.sqrt(a^2+b^2);
    appendItem(list, "("+a+","+b+")");
   // testpyth(a, b, c);
  }
}
```

I beleive it could be solutions to a system of a number of equations, but im not sure. 
Thank you in advance for any help.
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GIKG.png

Comment: These numbers are called [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple). There are [many efficient ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples) to generate them.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to generate all Pythagorean triples $a^2+b^2=c^2$ such that $a,b,c$ are integers?

Comment: @prets If - really - the question is about Pythagorean triples, what is the connection with the given graphics ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Good question. Certainly the provided code finds Pythagorean triples. Equally certainly the attached picture is not plotting $(x, y) = (a, b)$ the the title seems to suggest.

Comment: Incomprehensible. To begin with, equations have solutions, and problems have solutions, but theorems do not have solutions. So, what do you mean by "solution to the Pythagorean Theorem"?

Answer (score 1):

There are many formulas to generate Pythagorean triples and the most common one is Euclid's, which works but requires some restrictions on input to avoid generating trivial and imprimitive triples.
$$A=m^2-k^2\qquad B=2mk\qquad C=m^2+k^2$$

There is another formula that generates a Pythagorean triple for any pair of natural numbers $\space (n,k)\space$ with fewer imprimitives than any other formula I have seen.

\begin{align*}
&A=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k\\
&B=               &&2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\
&C=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k+2k^2
 \end{align*}

Using either formula, we will have
$$X=A\quad\text{and}\quad Y=B$$

and we can use these to generate a scatter plot similar to the one shown
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#/media/File:PrimitivePythagoreanTriplesRev08.svg).

Comment: [+1] I didn't know the second family of formulas. Do you have references ?

Comment: In fact, using https://approach0.xyz/search/ I found [this  reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3369742/305862), that you should remember.

Comment: @Jean Marie I developed the 2nd formula, out of ignorance in 2009, and have found no other references to it outside of MSE. It reveals unexpected things too, like the inradius of any triple generated by this formula is $\space (2n-1)k.$

Comment: Interesting indeed... Have you seen [this reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples) ?

Comment: @Jean Marie I have seen them but never paid that much attention because I like my formula so much. Here are more observations derived from my formula about the lines$\space (x,y,z)\space$ from the incircle center to the vertices

\begin{align*}
\text{inradius}=r&=(2n -1)k\\
x^2&=2(2n-1)^2k^2\\
y^2&=2k^2C\\
z^2&=(2n-1)^2C\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Interesting. But what is $C$ in the two last formulas ?

Comment: @Jean Marie 
\begin{align*}&C=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k+2k^2
\end{align*}
as per the formula I developed.

Comment: Besides, IMHO, the most unexpected way to generate (efficiently) **all** primitive triples is the matrix way with ternary tree given [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples).